# XDebug with Brackets - inactive debug buttons

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug, adobe-brackets

I have installed: 
 -> Xampp 3.2.2 (PHP 7.1.15),
 -> XDebug "installed: 2.9.5" (version from xdebug wizard)

 -> and BRACKETS 1.14 with PHP debugger extension

In debug window my buttons "RUN", "STOP" ect are greyed out and I keep seeing:

```
 Server started listening on port: 9000 idekey: xdebug
```

My file brackets.json:

```
    {
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "18px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "",
    "themes.theme": "dark-theme",
    "linting.collapsed": true,
    "livedev.multibrowser": false,
    "noDistractions": false,
    "smartIndent": false,
    "php-debugger.idekey": "xdebug",
    "php": {
        "enablePhpTooling": true,
        "executablePath": "C:\\XAMPP\\php\\php.exe",
        "memoryLimit": "4095M",
        "validateOnType": "false"
    }
 }
```

Apache PHP.ini

```
 output_buffering = off
 (...)
 [XDebug]
 zend_extension = c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
 xdebug.default_enable=1
 xdebug.idekey=xdebug
 xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
 xdebug.profiler_append = 0
 xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
 xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
 xdebug.profiler_output_dir = c:\xampp\tmp
 xdebug.remote_mode = req
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
 xdebug.remote_enable=1
 xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
 xdebug.remote_host = localhost
 xdebug.remote_log = c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt
 xdebug.remote_port = 9000
 xdebug.trace_output_dir = c:\xampp\tmp
 xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = -9999
 xdebug.show_local_vars = 0
 xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

My file test.php

```
 echo 'A';
 echo 'B';   <- here I put breakpoint (red dot)
 echo 'C';
```

Returns 'ABC' all the time. No matter if I use ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=xdebug or chrome xdebug helper extension: my breakpoints are not working at all. If I type something into PHP debugger window, I am receiving:

```
 An active debugging session is required for code evaluation.
```

I've tried hundreds of different settings, including changes in php.ini "on/offs" to 1/0, putting dll path into quotes, localhost to "127.0.0.1" but no one works. Of course I restarted Apache and brackets every time after setting changed. I like Brackets because it's simple look (I've just started learning php, and I wouldn't to learn complicated IDE at the time) and because of live preview feature. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found working settings. Maybe this will help someone:

```
 (...)
 output_buffering = off
 (...)
 [XDebug]
 zend_extension = c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
 xdebug.default_enable = 1
 xdebug.idekey = "xdebug"
 xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
 xdebug.profiler_append = 0
 xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
 xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
 xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
 xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
 xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
 xdebug.remote_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
 xdebug.remote_mode=req
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
 xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
 xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
 xdebug.remote_port = 9000
 xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
 xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = -9999
 xdebug.show_local_vars = 0
 xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

I am receiving sometimes "live preview" error, but this is another case to solve, not strictly related to xdebug, I believe...